# Finding the total energy of the network in steady state

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor, energy

i got a network below in steady state im trying to find the energy in the network by the capacitors and inductors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftYd1Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My attempt to the solution was:

1) i open circuited the capacitors, and short circuited the inductors

2) i used nodal analysis, grounded the bottom node

3) i made Va at the node between the 2H inductor and the middle 3ohm resistor

4) Vb is the node between the 3H inductor and the middle 3ohm resistor

5) Va is 5V, i got my Vb to equal to 16/3V

6) now im stuck cus i do not know what to do next

Comment: Your value for Vb is wrong. I get 15.3333 V.

Comment: @DaveTweed Do you mind showing me your method to work through tthis problem? i still haven't found out how to solve it

Comment: I simply replaced the 6ohm/6A Norton source with its Thevenin equivalent: 36V in series with 6 ohms. Then, it's a simple voltage divider between the 5V source and the 36V source: 5V + 1/3 * 31V = 15.3333V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

In DC steady state, the voltage at the top of the 5V supply and the top of the 4 ohm resistor will be the same.  Then your circuit just looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ckig.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use Thevenin's theorem to simplify the voltage divider on the left hand side, and you'll get a circuit containing just a voltage source, a current source, an inductor, and resistor.  The current through L1 will be 6A, so you can calculate the energy in that inductor.  The same current must flow into the Thevenin equivalent voltage source, so you can easily find the current through the first inductor by equating powers: \$V_{th}*6A = 5*I\$ and solving for I.  This will be the current through the first inductor.  The voltage across the capacitor in steady state will be 5 volts, so you know the energy in it.  Add them up to get the total energy in the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

1. open circuit capacitor, short inductors
2. Norton of 5 volts in series with 3 ohms = 5/3 amps in parallel with 3 ohms
3. 3 ohms in parallel with 6 ohms = 2 ohms
4. 5/3 amps + 6 amps into 2 ohms = 46/3 volts at "Vb"
5. 6 amps - (46/3 volts / 6 ohms) = 23/9 amps through 2H ("into" the 5 V source)
6. energy = 1/2 CV^2 + 1/2 LI^2 + 1/2 LI^2
7. (2*25 + 2*(23/9)^2 + 3*36)/2 = 6928/81 or 85.53 J